# C# Insert into SQL table is missing the first row from my datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I'm using the code below to insert data into a SQL table from a datagrid, the datagrid has 5 rows but only 4 are inserted into the table, the first row is missed off. I've narrowed the problem to updateTable below. Can you spot the problem? After an hour of trying I can't.

```
private void updateTable(OdbcConnection conn)
{
                int iCols = _DGV.ColumnCount;
                int iRows = _DGV.RowCount;
                int iIndex = 1;

                string strSql = GetInsertStatement(iCols);

                foreach(DataGridViewRow dr in _DGV.Rows)
                {
                    if (!dr.Visible)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    iIndex++;

                    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
                    for (int j = 0; j <= iCols - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (_DGV.Columns[j].Visible == false)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = strSql;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure each row in the grid is visible? IE, at the end of your loop (as it is written), does iIndex == iRows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
int iIndex = 0;
```

Comment: iIndex doesn't look like it's used anywhere.

Comment: I had tried that with no luck, the code isn't mine it belongs to a colleague who is currently off work ill.

Comment: @Jonas, you're right. How odd.

@Jade M, why is he checking .Visible all the time? I'm thinking some other code not shown is hiding something.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j <= iCols - 1; j++)
{
    if (_DGV.Columns[j].Visible == false)
  {
    continue;
  }
}
```

`j <= iCols - 1;` I think here is the problem, try to change that to `<= iCols`

Comment: Can you please provide some explanation to the questioner why this is solving his problem? See [answer]

Comment: I'm sure this problem is already solved :D I just don't notice when this question was asked